# How do I send MetaData HTTP POST Request

Tags: node.js, rest

Suppose i want to send these type of Requests which has "meta":{} inside the json data, how do I go about it?

I have this as json data

```
{
  "amount": 500,
  "narration": "Test Int'l bank transfers",
  "currency": "USD",
 "beneficiary_name": "Mark Cuban",
  "meta":
    {
     "AccountNumber": "09182972BH",
     "RoutingNumber": "0000000002993",
     "SwiftCode": "ABJG190",
     "BankName": "BANK OF AMERICA, N.A., SAN FRANCISCO, CA",
     "BeneficiaryName": "Mark Cuban",
     "BeneficiaryAddress": "San Francisco, 4 Newton",
     "BeneficiaryCountry": "US"
    }
}
```

If i try to send this in Postman , i get an Error , like this

[image: jq.png]

Then when I send this as a normal request like below, say something like this

```
{
  "account_bank":"044",
  "account_number":"09182972BH",
  "RoutingNumber":"0000000002993",
  "SwiftCode": "ABJG190",
  "amount":"450.40",
  "email":"john_kross2@yopmail.com",
  "narration":"test USD transfer",
  "currency":"NGN",
  "reference":"akhlm-pstmnpyt-rfxx007_PMCKDU_6876677",
  "debit_currency":"USD"
}
```

, it gives me this with HTTP 200, but does not work as I expect it to

[image: ob.png]

The code in Question that is supposed to work is Looking thus :

```
router.post("/us-transfer", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (
      !req.headers.authorization ||
      !req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ") ||
      !req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
    ) {
      return res.status(422).json({ message: "Please Provide Token!" });
    }

    var AccountNumber = req.body.AccountNumber;
    var RoutingNumber = req.body.RoutingNumber;
    var SwiftCode = req.body.SwiftCode;
    var amount = req.body.amount;
    var narration = req.body.narration;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var currency = req.body.currency;
    var reference = req.body.refernce;
    var debit_currency = req.body.debit_currency;
    var beneficiary_name = req.body.beneficiary_name;

    url = "https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/transfers";
    await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer FLWSECK_TEST-153740d351951b5f6d5ae8b903e0c467-X",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        AccountNumber: AccountNumber,
        RoutingNumber : RoutingNumber,
        SwiftCode : SwiftCode,
        amount: amount,
        narration: narration,
        currency: currency,
        reference: reference,
        debit_currency: debit_currency,
        beneficiary_name: beneficiary_name,
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(async (json) => {

        const debit = await User.find({ email: email});
        const debit_balance = parseInt(debit[0].balance);
        const debit_amt = debit_balance - amount;
        await User.findOneAndUpdate({email : email}, {$set: {balance: debit_amt}});

        const transactions = new Trans({
          email: email,
          narration: narration,
          credit: 0.0,
          debit: amount,
          amount: amount,
        });
        try {
          transactions.save();
          //res.send(savedUser);
          console.log("transaction saved");
        } catch (err) {
          //res.status(400).send(err);
          console.log(err);
        }

        //sendTransferConfirmation(email);
        return res.send({ error: false, data: json, message: "US Bank Transfer Complete" });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        throw err;
      });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

I do not seem to know what is going on. Kindly help.

Comment: JSON is just JSON, nested or not. There is at least one typo in the `us-transfer` endpoint (`refernce`) but it's not clear what actual **problem** you're having: sending the request? Reading the nested data (add a `meta` property to the object path)? Retrieving the user from wherever it is you're retrieving users from?

Comment: @DaveNewton I am trying to send data to make payments to US accounts so i am using Node.JS as a wrapper to interract with this endpoint for this. Other documentation can be found here https://developer.flutterwave.com/docs/making-payments/transfers/bank-accounts/#us-accounts

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't explain the actual problem. The error refers to *(the nebulous)* "line 264" which...? In the code the only `balance` I saw was `parseInt(debit[0].balance)`, which means `debit[0]` is null. `debit` is the confusingly-named result of trying to find a `User`; we don't know what that is but it looks Mongo-y so Mongoose? So pretending it's Mongoose means the user isn't being found, which makes sense since in the JSON with `meta` there's no email (which presumably you meant to get from `meta` but currently don't)...

Comment: The probem(s) are not explicitly described, with the flat JSON you say it doesn't work "as expected" but we don't know what's expected or what happens instead of what's expected, we don't know what went wrong with the nested JSON (which is perfectly fine on its own), etc.